# localStorage Auto Login Using Multiple Tokens

Tags: javascript, security, local-storage, autologin

I'm developing a Phonegap mobile application and enabling users to auto login if the token on localStorage matches a row in the database. At every login or update the user receives a new auto login token and it is stored locally.

As a higher level of protection, I would like to break the token into 4 tokens: 3 tokens containing parts of the token while the 4th contains a 'code'. On the back end, each 'code' will contain unique instructions on how to concat or parse the 3 tokens together. The resultant string would then be compared to the database row.

```
$token1 = $_POST['token1']; 
$token2 = $_POST['token2'];
$token3 = $_POST['token3'];
$token4 = $_POST['token4'];

if ( $token4 === '101' ) {
   // Just a quick example
   $requestToken = $token3 . $token1 . $token2;
}
```

Is this a silly implementation in order to raise security for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not much point in doing so. All of your tokens would be protected the same way, so an attacker could steal all of them in one go. Furthermore, especially in case of a mobile app that's relatively easy to decompile (but even if it's not easy), an attacker can find out with reasonable resources how stuff works.

So to me it's a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve, or against what threat you are trying to protect. It appears to be [security by obscurity](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Security_by_Design_Principles#Avoid_security_by_obscurity), which should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you - I was thinking the same thing that the tokens are all protected at the same level anyway. I was certain that some sort of obscurity to the data would be an added level of protection but you have convinced me otherwise.